# Atomic transaction between both the Realtime Database and Firestore in a Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want make use of the fast file update times in the real time database, but still use firestore. Is it possible to do something like this:

Have an object called `queue` that has a field called `lastValue`. When a cloud function is called over https I want to get the `lastValue` of the `queue`, add this to an object and save that object in the firestore database. Then I want to increment `lastValue` and save the `queue` back to the real time db. This should all be done atomically so that no two objects in the firestore database have the same `lastValue`.
This cloud function might be called many times per second.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't perform a single set of operations atomically between both Realtime Database and Firestore.  There are only atomic transactions for one or the other.

Comment: Ah this is so annoying. All I’m trying to do is create a queue where people can move up in the queue X spaces if necessary, but it seems to be so difficult in firebase. The 1/sec write time stops me from doing that on firestore and the lack of multiple sorts stops me on the rtdb

Comment: If you need more writes in a document than is scalable for Firestore, consider sharding your data to use multiple documents instead a single document.  That's the recommendation for counters.  You may have to get creative with it.  For example, with counters: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters

Comment: Thanks, I have considered that but it could get expensive and slow having to count the documents every single time. I think what I'll do is use the rtdb for everything and do the sort client side.